# Does the "by which" give correct meaning

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses, restrictive-clauses

What clause should I use to express following idea correctly?

> After that, polygon edges are extended and intersected ***by which*** leads a closed polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think this is an excerpt from construction rules of a polygon.

The **by...which** clause you have is neither grammatically correct nor meaningful. It can be one of these:

> 1. After that, polygon edges are extended and intersected *by which **we get*** closed polygon.
> 2. After that, polygon edges are extended and intersected *which **leads to a*** closed polygon.
> 3. After that, polygon edges are extended and intersected ***to construct*** a closed polygon.

There may be many more such possibilities, all depending on the text that preceded the excerpt.